# How to add a "Select one..." option in ZK combobox

Tags: java, combobox, zk

I'm using the ZK framework and I want to populate a combobox with the values of a given list , but I also want to include a "Select One..." option, as the combo is not required to have a value on submit.

My view looks like this:

```
<row>
    <hbox>
        Items:
    </hbox>
    <combobox width="100%" readonly="true" model="@load(vm.itemList)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.object.item)" >
        <template name="model">
            <comboitem label="@load(each.description)" />
        </template>
    </combobox> 
</row>
```

In the ViewModel I retrieve the list with a record set from the database and I don't want to add a record just for this and, if possible, I also want to avoid adding an empty Item on the list.

I think that should be possible to do something like this:

```
<combobox width="100%" readonly="true" model="@load(vm.itemList)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.object.item)" >
    <template name="model">
        <comboitem label="@load(each.description)" />
    </template>
    <comboitem label="Select One..."/>
</combobox>
```

But neither that or this works:

```
<combobox width="100%" readonly="true" model="@load(vm.itemList)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.object.item)" >
    <template name="model">
        <comboitem label="@load(each.description)" />
        <comboitem label="Select One..."/>
    </template>
</combobox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `getItemList` method of your view model so that it would add desired item to the list, something like the following:

```
public List getItemList() {
    List itemList = getItemsFromDatabase();
    YourItemClass item = new YourItemClass();
    item.setDescription("Select One...");
    itemList.add(item);
    return itemList;
}
```

EDIT: Another option is to use a [placeholder](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/InputElement#Placeholder) with the text "Select One..." and an additional button (and/or hotkey) for clearing selected item in the combobox.

Comment: Thank you for answering! That's the solution I went for and it solves the problem, but I don't really like it very much (I'm not complaining of your contribution), it adds the logic of controlling what value was selected before updating the parent object and removing it if it is this "fake" value.

Comment: I'll try the solution you suggest in your edit, it is very interesting, thank you!